# No active admin owned by uid 10204 for policy #2

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner in Android App Development. I'm trying to develop a simple app which uses device admin policies. When launching the app, it stops unfortunately and I see the exception mentioned in the title. Please help me. Following is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package eg.app7;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DevicePolicyManager dpm;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

    dpm.resetPassword("4279",0);
    try {
        dpm.lockNow();
        finish();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Intent it = new         Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        it.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, new ComponentName(this, DeviceAdminReceiver.class));
        startActivityForResult(it, 0);
    }



}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        dpm.lockNow();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Device administrator must be activated to lock the screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    finish();
}






}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="eg.app7">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <receiver android:name="android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

device_admin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-policies>
    <limit-password />
    <watch-login />
    <reset-password />
    <force-lock />
    <wipe-data />
    <expire-password />
    <encrypted-storage />
    <disable-camera />
</uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Please guide me where I'm wrong.

Comment: Got it! I've put dpm.resetPassword("4279",0) inside the try block and it works now.